# postman x-www-form-urlencoded returns null value for a mongodb date field set date.now during a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I am trying to test a post request on **`postman`** for a mongodb collection.

Everything works fine but the create date field i have set to  Date.now now is always null. this is my model definition below.

The ***create_date*** which i have set to Date.now and require always return a null value during a post request

````
export const add_eventSchema = new Schema({
    event_title:{
        type:String,
        require:'Enter a title for the event'
    },
    creater_id:{
        type:String,
        require:'Enter your username'
    },
    event_mode:{
        type:String,default:"Physical",
        
    },
    event_type:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    event_description:{
        type:String
    },
    event_date:{
        type:Date
    },
    event_time:{
        type:String
    },
    **create_date:{
        type: Date, default: Date.now,
        require:true**
        }
 
}); ```
````

Comment: I mean the create_date field in the collection is always returning a null value, when it should just return the default date because i am using the date.Now function

Comment: it should be work, probably you are missing something, make sure you are not passing empty or null in create_date in post request.

Comment: The option `require` should be `required` and should contain true or false, or a function that returns true or false, that determines whether that field is required. Also as turivishal mentions, ensure you are not passing `create_date` in the body of the post request.